# I have followed all the steps to connect PHP to mongo database. However, once I use a var dump on my data, I get nothing

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp

I have created a database called an "example" and a collection called "cars", which have inserted data into through the command line. When I run the var_dump, I get nothing. Is there something wrong with my connection ? Or is it something else. I don't get an error message, so don't know what is wrong. Am I missing something? I am new to Apache, Mongo, and PHP.

Also, I have installed the php driver for my mongo and input the extensions to the php.ini.

```
<?php
$connection = new MongoClient();
$collection = $connection->example->cars;

$cursor = $collection->find();
foreach ( $cursor as $id => $value )
{
    echo "$id: ";
    var_dump( $value );
}
?>
```

Comment: And what do you get when you var_dump $collection?

Comment: Well then I would say your problem is coming there.  Does $connection have anything? You should really be checking for errors at each point i.e. if $connection is false.

Comment: I checked the connection and I don't get any errors.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mongoclient.construct.php  Okay so are you following the next logical step and seeing if $connection->example is giving what you expect?  You ned to explain what you have tried and what research you have done.